# Rails 3.2 - Create and Update button using GET instead of POST & PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When navigating towards my universities/new page HTTP works as I would expect. Here's the server output for generating my form.

[image]

Now when I fill in data and select f.submit, my logs show that Rails is starting GET.

[image]

The same thing happens when I attempt to edit an existing resource. Here's the correct GET request to pull up the resource.

[image]

And when I select the update button, instead of PUT, my logs look like this.
[image]

I've read over some closely related SO questions and realized that my issues began when I tried to add vendor assets to the application. I haven't got Bower to work properly yet, and failed to correctly implement my site's template using the Rails Guide's so maybe this is the reason why things are going unexpectedly. I am hoping to find a solution to the proper HTTP verb being sent with the requests. And I'm hoping to better understand if I can tackle the .js templating issues with bower or asset pipeline in another scope. Or is the addition of my external template files causing Rails to mix something up.

Your help is appreciated.

Here are my other relevant files for illustration.

```
# universities_controller.rb

 class UniversitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_university, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @universities = University.all
  end

  def new
    @university = University.new
  end

  def create
    @university = University.new(params[:university])
    if @university.save
      redirect_to  @university, success: 'University added!'
    else
      render :new, error: 'There was an error processing your University'
    end
  end

  def show
    @teams = @university.teams
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @university.update_attributes(params[:university])
      redirect_to @university, method: :put, success: 'University updated!'
    else
      render :edit, error: 'There was an error updating your University'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @university.delete
    flash.now[:notice] = 'You sure?'
    redirect_to universities_path
  end

  private
  def get_university
    @university = University.find(params[:id])
  end
end

# events_controller.rb

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_teams, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
  before_filter :get_event, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @upcoming_events = Event.upcoming
    @past_events = Event.past
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    if @event.save
      redirect_to event_path(@event), success: 'Event created!'
    else
      render :new, error: 'There was an error processing your form'
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      redirect_to event_path(@event), success: 'Event updated!'
    else
      render :edit, error: 'There was an error updating your form'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event.delete
    redirect_to events_path
  end

  private
  def get_event
    @event = Event.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def get_teams
    @teams = Team.all
  end
end

# universities/_form.html.erb
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="content bg-base section">  
        <div class="ribbon ribbon-highlight">
            <ol class="breadcrumb ribbon-inner">
                <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Universities', universities_path %></li>
                <li class="active" title="universities/new"><em>Form</em></li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.ribbon.ribbon-highlight-->
            <h3 class="page-title" style="margin-left: 35.5%;">
                <em style="color: #6699CC">Add</em> a University
            </h3>
            <form role="form" style="margin-left: 33%;">
                <%= form_for @university, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
                <% if @university.errors.any? %>
                    <div class="error_messages">
                        <h3>Please correct the following errors.</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <% @university.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                                <li><%= msg %></li>
                            <% end %>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'text_field', 
                            placeholder: 'University Name', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :url, class: 'text-field', 
                            placeholder: 'University Website', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">                
                    <%= f.text_area :address, 
                            placeholder: 'University Address', 
                            size: '32x3', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'text-field', 
                            placeholder: 'University City', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'text-field', 
                            placeholder: 'University State', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'text-field', 
                            placeholder: 'University Zip', 
                            class: 'form-control input-lg',
                            style: 'width: 50%;'
                             %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15%;">
                    <%= f.submit 'Create University!', 
                            options = { 
                                                    method: :post, 
                                                    class: 'btn btn-primary' 
                                                } %>
                </div>
                <% end %>   
            </form>
    </div><!--/#content.content.bg-base.section-->
</div><!--/#main.container-->

# events/edit.html.erb
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="content bg-base section">  
        <div class="ribbon ribbon-highlight">
            <ol class="breadcrumb ribbon-inner">
                <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to 'Events', events_path %></li>
                <li class="active" title="events/new">
                        <em>Edit Event</em>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.ribbon.ribbon-highlight-->
        <h6 class="page-title" style="margin-left: 34%;">
            <span style="color: #FF3333"><em>Edit</em></span> an Event
        </h6>
        <form role="form" style="margin-left: 33%;">
            <%= form_for [@team, @event], html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>
            <% if @event.errors.any? %>
                <div class="error_messages">
                    <h3>Please correct the following errors.</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                            <li><%= msg %></li>
                        <% end %>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_field :author, class: 'text_field', 
                        placeholder: 'Your name', class: 'form-control input-lg', 
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="pull-left">
                <%= f.label 'Home Team' %><br />
                <%= f.select :home_team_id, 
                        @teams.map { |team| [team.name, team.id] }, 
                        class: 'form-control input-lg' %>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 37%;">
                <%= f.label 'Away Team', style: 'margin-left: 6%; margin-top: -1%;' %><br />    
                <%= f.select :away_team_id, 
                        @teams.map { |team| [team.name, team.id] } %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">    
                <%#= f.label 'Away Team' %><br />   
                <%#= f.select :away_team_id, 
                        @teams.map { |team| [team.name, team.id] } %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.select :kind, @teams.map { |team| [team.sport_type] }, class: 'form-control input-lg text_field', 
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_field :home_team_score, class: 'text_field', 
                        placeholder: 'Home team score', class: 'form-control input-lg', 
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_field :away_team_score, class: 'text_field', 
                        placeholder: 'Away team away_team_score', class: 'form-control input-lg', 
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_field :winner, class: 'text_field', 
                        placeholder: 'Winning team name', class: 'form-control input-lg', 
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_area :details, class: 'text_area', 
                        placeholder: 'Details about the event', 
                        class: 'form-control input-lg', size: '10x3',
                        style: 'width: 50%;' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.datetime_select :event_on, 
                        class: 'datetime_select form-control input-lg' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 12.5%;">
                <%= f.submit 'Update Event!', 
                    options = { 
                                            method: :put, 
                                            class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success' 
                                        } %>
                <%= link_to :cancel, events_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger', style: 'margin-top: 2.3%;' %>
            </div>
            <% end %>   

        </form>
    </div><!--/#content.content.bg-base.section-->
</div><!--/#main.container-->

# layouts/application.html.erb to demonstrate how I've connected to css and js

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Sevendaysports</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render partial: 'layouts/summarize_header' %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </body>
</html>

# config/routes.rb

Sevendaysports::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home', controller: 'static_pages', action: 'home', as: 'root'

  match 'static_pages/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', as: :contact

  devise_for :users
  resources :articles
  resources :medias

  resources :events do
    resources :articles
    resources :medias
  end

  resources :universities do 
    resources :teams 
  end

  resources :teams do
    resources :events
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :medias
  end

  resources :teams do
    resources :medias
  end

  resources :events do
    resources :medias
  end

  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

My assets are a mess at the moment but I'll include them upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [How do forms with PATCH, PUT, or DELETE methods work?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark) Basically it is a GET with a hidden "_method" field to get around the limitation of some browsers not implementing PUT and DELETE.

This is handled when you use `form_for`. What does your `form_for` line and routes look like?

Comment: The form_for in question is under # universities/_form.html.erb, I've tried substituting method: :post with method: "patch" to no avail. I will look at 3.2.14 guides to see if its covered in the same section as well.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the scroll bars. I see you are nesting your `form_for` inside another form. This could be the problem. Can you remove the wrapper form and see if that helps?

Comment: That did it, thanks JosephL! I'll look into adding a roll to form_for (like in my <form role="form"></form> wrapper).

Comment: @SirRamonGabriel Yep so that would look like `<%= form_for @university, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form", style: "margin-left: 33%;" } do |f| %>`